# Why is scikit-learn's random forest using so much memory?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, scikit-learn, decision-tree, random-forest

I'm using scikit's Random Forest implementation:

```
sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, 
                                        max_features="auto", 
                                        max_depth=10)
```

After calling `rf.fit(...)`, the process's memory usage increases by 80MB, or **0.8MB** per tree (I also tried many other settings with similar results. I used `top` and `psutil` to monitor the memory usage)

A binary tree of depth 10 should have, at most, `2^11-1 = 2047` elements, which can all be stored in one dense array, allowing the programmer to find parents and children of any given element easily.

Each element needs an index of the feature used in the split and the cut-off, or 6-16 bytes, depending on how economical the programmer is. This translates into **0.01-0.03MB** per tree in my case.

Why is scikit's implementation using 20-60x as much memory to store a tree of a random forest?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Each decision (non-leaf) node stores the left and right branch integer indices (2 x 8 bytes), the index of the feature used to split (8 bytes), the float value of the threshold for the decision feature (8 bytes), the decrease in impurity (8 bytes). Furthermore leaf nodes store the constant target value predicted by the leaf.

You can have a look at the [Cython class definition](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/tree/_tree.pyx#L1375) in the source code for the details.

Comment: If I train on some data using 10 estimators (the default), about 2.2 GB is used, if I train on the same data using 200 estimators, the memory usage is about 2.2 GB. Do you know why the memory usage would be almost the same with 20 times the number of trees?

Comment: This is strange. Maybe you can try to use [memory_profiler](https://github.com/fabianp/memory_profiler) to understand how / why this is happening.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was partly incorrect in my earlier statement. What I really observed is that double or triple the number of estimators seemed to make little difference, but does make some. Indeed, increasing the n_estimators 20 times does make a difference, but a small one, maybe 10% more memory will be used instead of 2,000% like you might expect. I just wanted to clarify this for future readers.